# How to copy some of the data from one MongoDB to another

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I have an existing MongoDB dump and I would like to cherry pick some of the data to a clean DB.

Is dumping a single collection and restoring them (mongodump & mongorestore) the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to this by using the `--filter '<JSON>'` option on `mongorestore`.

That's like the first argument of `db.find()`.

If you just want to filter by collection `--collection <collection>`

See more info in the [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongorestore/)